# Check if the macro expands to undefined

Tags: expansion, key-value, csname

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clefval}
\begin{document}
\TheKey{test}{zez}
\def\mymacro{\TheValue{test}}
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\V@test \mymacro \else empty \fi
\ifdefined\mymacro \mymacro \else empty \fi
\end{document}
```

On first pass, when there is no .aux file yet, trying to use `\mymacro` leads to the weird error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "A0.
```

The implementation of `clefval` builds up the resulting macro name with `\csname`, without a guarantee that it exists. As MWE demonstrates, I can check if that name is defined, but in general case I need to check it via `\mymacro`, which does not work that way. Trying to expand it before checking leads to the same error.

Comment: `\csname mymacro\endcsname` just becomes `\relax` if `\mymacro` wasn't defined (it also makes `\mymacro` become `\relax` from that point on).

Comment: Well the issue is that `clefval` uses `^^a0` as the place-holder for undefined material, but buried away inside an internal macro. I'd be tempted to patch/change that internal macro, if you are determined to use the package. Is that an option?

Comment: @JosephWright well, the package is pretty simple, so if it is that troublesome, I would prefer to make a custom solution instead. I don't even need it's 2-pass functionality, as all keys are defined at preamble stage, so a set of macros with the same prefix should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strange reasons, `clefval` uses a strange byte in its code.

If you just need a set of macros for storing values and such storing is done in the preamble, you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defkey}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{bodqhrohro@#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\getkey}[1]{%
  \ifcsname bodqhrohro@#1\endcsname
    \@nameuse{bodqhrohro@#1}%
  \else
    ??????
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\keyexistTF}[1]{%
  \ifcsname bodqhrohro@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\defkey{Test}{test}
\defkey{X}{x}

\begin{document}

Test: \getkey{Test}

X: \getkey{X}

Y: \getkey{Y}

\keyexistTF{X}{Hurray!}{Boooh!}

\keyexistTF{Y}{Hurray!}{Boooh!}

\end{document}
```

[image]